# Magento image not showing correctly

Tags: php, magento

I am working with Magento 1.9 and I am running into a problem I do not understand.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6i7rD9u.png]

For some reason the first two images display correctly, pathes and everything appear to be right.

But the last image just won't show and displays the magento default image instead.

Any idea what may be causing the problem?

I have tried the following code

```
<i>
    <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(70, 70); ?>
    <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>
</i>
```

Comment: Yes, the Images are displaying correctly in the admin panel.

Comment: If anyone runs into the same problem: Keeping the images below 1mb fixes the problem. For me anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Should try the below

```
    Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail')
->resize($width, $height);
```

You should not create same size image of a same product in same page.

Comment: Sorry, I was indeed resizing it but removed it as I thought there may be memory problems.

Comment: Well this isn't exactly wrong but it's not fixing the issue. After clearing cache etc. It's still not displaying the third image, instead it keeps showing the default magento image..